# Return random values from multple excel tables

Tags: excel

I need to generate some unique part numbers that have to be selected from 14 different tables in excel.
The part numbers are 15 characters long with the first 2 characters coming from the first table and the rest with 1 character each.    The tables only have 2 columns one for a description and the other with 1 alphanumeric indicator.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?  I'm not sure exactly on where to start looking up how to do this.

I'm willing to use excel or code if it's easy enough.

Edit: removed the word random and changed to Unique.  My bad.

Comment: A simple way to do this, is next to each "table", create a formula to generate a random number, and pull out the related item from the table into that cell. (so the table is listed in rows 3+ .. but your "random item" always shows up in row 1 .. for example).  Repeat for each row. Name those cells ... once that's done, have VBA script that just splices the values together, and saves them in another cell.  Each time it saves it, the random function will "regen" another set of values.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.  Is there anyway you can expound upon it a bit, I'm kind of a newb.  I think you want me to add another row with a rand() and use that somehow to pull out the information.  I'm just not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: I'd use RANDBETWEEN, myself.  And I'd probably setup 1 cell to count the number of valid items in the table (so if the table updates, I don't need to update the count), then use OFFSET to pull the item based on the result of RANDBETWEEN ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say we have two tables, one in column **C** and the other in column **E** like:

[image]

To make random picks from these tables, in **A1** enter:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$7,RANDBETWEEN(1,7)) & INDEX($E$1:$E$11,RANDBETWEEN(1,11))
```

The same technique can be used on more than two tables.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for!  Someone upvote this guy, I can't yet :)

Comment: @pnuts  .........you may be correct.........I'll wait for the Poster to request an **EDIT** if it is necessary.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if my vernacular was off.  I needed random pulls from the tables to create unique part numbers.  the only issue i need to work out now is how to add constraints inside it.  Like when A is selected from table 1 then b cannot be selected from table 2 and so forth.  But I understand that enough to be able to research it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

an example of how you might setup a table and a random pick from it:

Headers:

B2 : `Part`
C2 : `Desc`

(test) Data:

B3 : `123`

B4 : `234`

B5 : `345`

C3 : `asdf`

C4 : `qwer`

C5 : `zxcv`

Count:

A2 : `=COUNTA(B2:B1048576)-1`

Random pick:

A1 : `=RANDBETWEEN(1,A2)`

"Copy" the item to the top row for easier access by other processes:

B1 : `=OFFSET(B2,$A1,0,1,1)`

C1 : `=OFFSET(C2,$A1,0,1,1)`

You'll have to take those and rework for you case .. but that's probably how I'd try to setup the basic logic.